# Rxjs: get latest values from multiple observables later after they emitted

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have multiple observables that emit values during the lifetime of the page. For example:

```
chartData$: Observable;
tableData$: Observable;
filterData$: Observable;
```

At any time user can click the 'Download' button, and get the JSON combining the values that were last emitted from each of these observables:

```
downloadButtonClicked$.pipe(
    combine chartData$, tableData$ and filterData$    // <- how do I get latest values here?
).subscribe(([chart, table, filter]) => downloadJson(chart, table, filter))
```

but the `downloadJson` function shouldn't be called when any of these 3 observables emit values as part of page lifecycle, only on Download click.

**TLDR;**

working most elegant solution (as suggested by Mike)
https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jm3zma?file=index.ts

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```js
combineLatest([chartData$, tableData$, filterData$]).pipe(
  switchMap(result => downloadButtonClicked$.pipe(map(() => result)))
).subscribe(([chart, table, filter]) => {
  downloadJson(chart, table, filter);
});
```

Whenever `chartData$`, `tableData$`, or `filterData$` emits a new value it will create a new inner subscription to `downloadButtonClicked$` passing down the new data.

Note: the subscription will not be created until all of `chartData$`, `tableData$`, and `filterData$` have emitted their first value. If you need the download to still trigger in this case then you can use `defaultIfEmpty`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the last value from each of them before every single source Observable completes you can use `forkJoin()` that will emit only once after all of them complete.

If you want to emit on every emission from each source Observable you can use `combineLatest`.

Edit:

You can chain each source Observable with `shareReplay(1)` so when you subscribe to them you'll get the latest value.

```
const chartDataShared$ = chartData$.pipe(shareReplay(1));
tableDataShared$ = ...;
filterDataShared$ = ...;

combineLatest([chartDataShared$, tableDataShared, filterDataShared$]).pipe(
  take(1)
);
```

This way you'll get the latest values emitted from each one of them. However, this means that in other parts of you code you'll need to use eg. `chartDataShared$` instead of `chartData$`.

Comment: I want to get the values when 'Download' is clicked. Kind of like 'current state' of each observable.

Comment: Ok, so what't the problem?

Comment: not when they complete. And not on every emission. Only on button click.

Comment: See update. However it requires changes to your code.

Comment: thanks. But 'Download' button shouldn't be one-time use. User should click and download as many times as he wants.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You'll need to make a stackblitz demo or something.

Comment: I was doing `take(1)` in wrong place. Here's working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fnbycw?file=index.ts). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use [`withLatestFrom`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/withLatestFrom).

```ts
downloadButtonClicked$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(chartData$, tableData$, filterData$)
).subscribe(([_, chart, table, filter]) => downloadJson(chart, table, filter))
```

The observable will only emit when `downloadButtonClicked$` emits and combines its value with the latest values from `chartData$`, `tableData$` and `filterData$`.

Answer (score 1):

combineLastest will emit once all the observables have emitted. You can use switchMap to switch from downloadButtonClicked$.

```
downloadButtonClicked$.pipe(
   switchMap(
     () => combineLatest([chartData$, tableData$, filterData$])
   )
).subscribe(([chart, table, filter]) => downloadJson(chart, table, filter));
```

Comment: this also calls downloadJson when the input observables are triggered by other actions. But I only want it to be called when 'Download' is clicked.